# Passing file arguments to script in Lua

Tags: file-io, lua

I need to read a input file which name I do not know.

I know that in C we can do this:

```
FILE *Ifile;
File *Ofile;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // Input and Output files
    Ifile = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    Ofile = fopen(argv[2],"w");

  (More code)
}
```

and then call "`./cprogram <any file name>.txt  <any file name>.txt`"

Can I do something like this with .Lua scripts?

Comment: Command line parameters of Lua script are available as `arg[1]`, `arg[2]`,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  From the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#7):

> Before starting to run the script, `lua` collects all arguments in the command line in a global table called `arg`. The script name is stored at index 0, the first argument after the script name goes to index 1, and so on.

For example, you could do the following:

```
if #arg < 2 then
    print ("usage: lua " .. arg[0] .. " <ifile> <ofile>")
    return
end

local ifile = io.open(arg[1], "r")
local ofile = io.open(arg[2], "w")
if not ifile or not ofile then
    print ("Error: could not open files")
    return
end
```